# Given a symmetric matrix $A$, find $P$ such that $P^T A P$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> Given $$A =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ find a matrix $P$ such that $P^T A P$ orthogonally diagonalizes $A$. Verify that $P^TAP$ is diagonal.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you should find eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: @Suhail: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808469/find-a-matrix-p-that-orthogonally-diagonalizes-a-and-determine-p-1ap?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183514/orthogonal-diagonalization-of-a-matrix?rq=1

Comment: @TedShifrin: Do you have any relations to [Lenoid Shifrin](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin)? :)

Comment: @H.R. Not that I know of, although we could be distant cousins or something. Same is true of some non-mathematicians of whom I'm aware with the same patronym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$.  Since $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, the eigenvectors should be orthogonal if the eigenvalues are distinct (which it is in this case): if they were not distinct you might have to use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to make the eigenvectors orthogonal.
Divide each by its length, so they are orthonormal.  Then form the matrix $P$ whose columns are those orthonormal eigenvectors.

Comment: Got it! My solution matched the back of the book. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy even without calculating any eigenvalues or eigenvectors explicitly. Note that $A=5(uv^T+vu^T)$, where $u=(0,1,0)^T$ and $v=\frac15(3,0,4)^T$ are already two orthonormal vectors. So, if you take $w=\frac15(4,0,-3)^T$, then $Q=(u,v,w)$ is real orthogonal and
$$
A=5Q\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0\\ &&0}Q^T.
$$
Thus the problem boils down to the orthogonal diagonalisation of $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$. Yet this $2\times2$ matrix geometrically represents the reflection about the line $x=y$. So, it is immediate that
$$
A=5Q\pmatrix{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}&\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac1{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\\ &&1}\pmatrix{1\\ &-1\\ &&0}\pmatrix{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}&\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac1{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\\ &&1}Q^T.
$$
Absorb the factor $5$ into the diagonal matrix in the middle, you are done.